# Finding root-mean-square speed of neon using kinetic energy

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, energy, kinetic-theory-of-gases

> Find the root-mean-square speed of $\ce{Ne}$ atoms at the temperature at which their kinetic energy is $\pu{6.24 kJ mol-1}.$

I tried using the kinetic energy formula

$$\mathrm{KE} = \frac{mv^2}{2},$$

but I don't really understand how to achieve the necessary values.

I tried to do it by converting mass of one atom to mass of a mole since the given energy is per mole, but I'm still not getting the answer. I understand that I need to do $\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M}},$ where $R= \pu{8.3145 J mol^-1 K^-1}$ and $M = 20,$ but how would I get the temperature?

Comment: Hi Carol, did you convert mass of one atom to mass of a mole since your energy is per mole? You might find this helpful :)   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_speed

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Finally, we have an important policy: your questions (especially [homework questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/189)), should show your own work or thinking that you have already done in an initial attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @Carol I'd probably use $E_k=\frac{3}{2}NKT$ to get the temperature and then the formula you quote :)

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the comments by @AngusTheMan we use the equation

$$\mathrm{KE_{avg}} = \frac{3}{2}kT,$$

but ultimately we are looking for the $v_\mathrm{rms}$, so we'll also use

$$v_\mathrm{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{3RT}{M}}.$$

You've been given your $\mathrm{KE_{avg}},$ $R$ and $k$ are constants, and $M$ is the mass of 1 mole of $\ce{Ne}$. We can set all of these equal and the solution will come from

$$v_\mathrm{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{3 \cdot R\cdot\mathrm{KE_{avg}}\cdot\frac{2}{3k}}{M}}.$$

Comment: In the light of [Hint answers revisited](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/hint-answers-revisited), it would be nice if the answer would actually contain an answer and wouldn't end abruptly.